# What tech stack can be recommended for achieving live queries aka changefeeds aka realtime push?

Tags: push-notification, pagination, stream

Requirements:

- Payload Data is **JSON** (Document)
- must be have **pagination support**
- must have **orderBy** support by fields in the Document
- **replay** changes for timeframe

With rethinkdb (one solution which lacks pagination and replay) an example live query would look like:

```
r.table('game').orderBy('score').limit(3).changes()
```

And an example document would be

```
{'player': 'zoe',​ 'score': 78}
```

Any alternative techstack/system/db which you can recommend as stable and scalable in production use case which fullfills these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Always greatly depends... But graphql rocks the shit... And leaves you with a broad choice of technologies...
The real-time part is called Subscriptions...

Specs:
http://graphql.org/
Tutorials Front-end/Backend:
https://www.howtographql.com
Grapql as a Service (Really cool for checking it out quickly):
https://www.graph.cool

Comment: GraphQL unfortunately has just simple push (graphql subscription) at the moment. They are working on a live query spec but have not yet found out a scalable generic way of doing that. So graphql is unfortunately not the solution for that requirement (although I like graphl :-).

Comment: Reference to the discussion about the graphql live query spec: https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/284

Comment: Hmm... I think you can easily implement pagination and replay by yourself? Those things are not really are technical restriction... And you can subscribe to a query via graphql - and get the changes pushed if something new fitting the subscription is inserted to the database ( at least that is how I experienced it). Maybe update your requirements to be more specific about your real-time requirements...

Comment: As far as I have read that threat... I really don't see the big difference between live queries and subscriptions...  I am doing this with mutation/subscriptions (apollo-client) in graphql. But maybe it's just a technicality or lack of understanding on my part. If rethink db is doing what you need, just implement the pagination and reply functionality... That should be possible in all database technologies I have worked with...

Comment: You are right regarding rethinkdb. I am interested in getting alternatives to rethinkdb. I am researching this topic since about a year and I want to make sure that I don't oversee a technology which fits these requirements. As these requirements are quite applicable to a lot modern web apps which offer realtime edits I am hoping that there are some other technologies around for this requirements.

Comment: Regarding graphql: I am not aware of subscribing to an ordered and paginated graphql query in a way that scales. But maybe I missed that. Can you point me to some resources from where you got that info?

Comment: Well it does... it even is mentioned in the link you provided to the discussion yourself... This feature wouldn't make much sense - but try google something like graphql chat-app may find you something. But as i mentioned, for example in my application - i got a table of links i run a paged query on - In my first client i am displaying the first 5 links - in the second i display the 3rd page aka links 11-15... I now upvote link 11 - i don't receive the upvote notification in client one, as i don't display the page... now i upvote link 5 in client two... i now receive the upvote-notification.

Comment: Watch talk Rodrigo Muñoz - GraphQL Live: Reactive Queries at Facebook https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSw05rJaCpA - From the presentation: Subscriptions and Live-Queries are interchangable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with https://firebase.google.com (Firestore)

I know this will lock you in the Google Ecosystem but in my experience, it's easy to setup, works pretty well and the costs compared to maintaining your own full stack is good.

There are also many packages making good use of their API depending on if you are using React/Angular.